# How to get mouse position on isometric grid

Tags: java, lwjgl, isometric

I am making a simple(ish) java game in an isometric perspective using lwjgl and I cant figure out how to get the mouse position in the isometric view. Thanks in advance.

Note: the squares are 64x64, window is 640x480, done using a 2d array, and the grid marked "1" in the image below is supposed to be "0".

[image]

Comment: I hope this [link](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/623749-get-the-mouse-position-on-isometric-grid/) will help you

Comment: see [Improving performance of click detection on a staggered column isometric grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917976/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
mouse_grid_x = floor((mouse_y / tile_height) + (mouse_x / tile_width));
mouse_grid_y = floor((-mouse_x / tile_width) + (mouse_y / tile_height));
```

Where `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` are your mouse screen coordinates. You will need to render one line at a time. This is just the basic start for any isometric map game you build.

**Tip**: Use a good matrix calculator tool like wims to do the plot matrix calculation.